# Mono for Android not appearing in the MonoDevelop options

Tags: windows, monodevelop

I have installed Mono for Android and MonoDevelop as per instructions on the install page for Windows. (http://mono-android.net/Installation/Windows).  However the "Mono for Android SDKs" option does not appear in the options dialog.

I have reinstalled MonoDevelop 2.6.3 Beta, but no luck.  Any one see this issue before?

#### Update:

Found it.  I had to reload the repositories, they didn't appear initially...however, now I have an exception when I try to access the options:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Posix, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Found it.  I had to reload the repositories, they didn't appear initially...however, now I have an exception when I try to access the options:

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Posix, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: I have the same problem with my version. I downloaded the stable 2.4 version of Monodevelop and then uninstalled and installed the beta version 2.6.3. I thought maybe it was a registry error or a misplaced .dll on my side due to the double installation, but I haven't been able to solve it yet. Did you take the same path as me? Or did you only install the beta version?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the GTK# runtime library only has the version 2.0.0.0 of the file Mono.Posix.dll. I have done my setup using the beta version and still am facing this issue. If only I could get hold of the Mono.Posix.dll version 4.0.0.0 I could try replacing that file in my GTK# installation directory and see what happens.

UPDATE : It seems the latest version (4.0.0.0) of the missing file can be found if one installs http://mono.ximian.com/monobuild/preview/archive/2.10.2/windows-installer/5/mono-2.10.2-gtksharp-2.12.10-win32-5.exe and copy the Mono.Posix.dll from the installed directory to the Plugin Folder

Copy from  C:\Program Files\Mono-2.10.2\lib\mono\4.0\Mono.Posix.dll

Paste in C:\Users\YOUR_LOGON\AppData\Local\MonoDevelop-2.6\Addins\MonoDevelop.MonoAndroid.2.6.4\

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There's a new version of the Mono for Android addin, 2.6.5.3, which fixes this issue. It's available in the Add-in manager from the Beta channel (which should be enabled by default), so if you refresh the Updates list you should see it.

The release notes for the addin are here: http://android.xamarin.com/Releases/MfA_Addin/2.6.5.3