# Creating a MonoDevelop application

Tags: android, monodevelop, xamarin.android

I'm trying to create a [Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29)-for-Android application in [MonoDevelop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MonoDevelop). I'm on Windows 7 64-bit, and my MonoDevelop version is 2.6 Beta 3.

When I enter an application name and hit the forward button, it gives me the following errors,

1. File Activity1.cs could not be written.
2. File Resources could not be written.
3. File Properties could not be written.
4. File Assets could not be written.

What's the problem?

#### Error details for error 1

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectFile MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectFileEventArgs.get_ProjectFile()'.

   at MonoDevelop.MonoDroid.MonoDroidProject.OnFileAddedToProject(ProjectFileEventArgs e)

   at MonoDevelop.Projects.Project.NotifyFileAddedToProject(IEnumerable`1 objs)

   at MonoDevelop.Projects.Project.OnItemsAdded(IEnumerable`1 objs)

   at MonoDevelop.Projects.DotNetProject.OnItemsAdded(IEnumerable`1 objs)

   at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectItemCollection`1.NotifyAdded(IEnumerable`1 items, Boolean comesFromParent)

   at

    MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectItemCollection`1.MonoDevelop.Projects.IItemListHandler.InternalAdd(IEnumerable`1 objs, Boolean comesFromParent)

       at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectItemCollection`1.NotifyAdded(IEnumerable`1 items, Boolean comesFromParent)

       at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectItemCollection`1.OnItemAdded(T item)

       at MonoDevelop.Projects.ItemCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, T item)

       at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(T item)

       at MonoDevelop.Projects.Project.AddFile(String filename, String buildAction)

       at MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.SingleFileDescriptionTemplate.AddFileToProject(SolutionItem policyParent, Project project, String language, String directory, String name)

       at MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.SingleFileDescriptionTemplate.AddToProject(SolutionItem policyParent, Project project, String language, String directory, String name)

       at MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.ProjectDescriptor.InitializeItem(SolutionItem policyParent, ProjectCreateInformation projectCreateInformation, String defaultLanguage, SolutionEntityItem item)
```

Get similar details for other errors.

This is what I get when I install the AddIn:

[image]

Also when I hit Tools>Options>Other>Mono for Android SDK's, I get the following error(and error details) in a pop-up

> Un-handled exception

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Posix, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

   at MonoDevelop.MonoDroid.Gui.MonoDroidSdkSettingsWidget.Build()

   at MonoDevelop.MonoDroid.Gui.MonoDroidSdkSettingsWidget..ctor()

   at MonoDevelop.MonoDroid.Gui.MonoDroidSdkSettings.CreatePanelWidget()

   at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Dialogs.OptionsDialog.CreatePageWidget(SectionPage page)

   at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Dialogs.OptionsDialog.ShowPage(OptionsDialogSection section)

   at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Dialogs.OptionsDialog.OnSelectionChanged(Object s, EventArgs a)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)

   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)

   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)

   at GLib.Signal.ClosureInvokedCB(Object o, ClosureInvokedArgs args)

   at GLib.SignalClosure.Invoke(ClosureInvokedArgs args)

   at GLib.SignalClosure.MarshalCallback(IntPtr raw_closure, IntPtr return_val, UInt32 n_param_vals, IntPtr param_values, IntPtr invocation_hint, IntPtr marshal_data)
```

Comment: Sounds like you don't have write permission for the directory you're trying to save the project in.

Comment: Well I do have write permission for that directory, changed the directory path, but the error persists.

Comment: Okay, I'm afraid I'm in the dark then. Hopefully someone with more experience of MonoDroid will see this soon...

Comment: @Jon Have added some error details, hope it helps clarify the question further. Thank you for having a look :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same error and found a solution by seeing Daniel Soto's answer to *[Error creating Android app](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/WyDoAOHcnu79I829djUd)*. Basically, install the 2.5.90.3 trunk build of MonoDevelop [here](http://monodevelop.com/files/Windows/trunk-builds/MonoDevelop-2.5.90.3.msi).

I was able to continue.

Comment: were you able to create a `helloWorld` mono for android app?

Comment: well, it worked :) the only problem I'm having now is when I hit `Tools > Options > Other > Mono for Android SDKs` I get an error saying `unhandled exception`

Comment: Assuming it's the same that I got, you need an updated Posix dll.  See the answer in this Stack Overflow question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202820/mono-for-android-not-appearing-in-the-monodevelop-options

Comment: would be grateful if you would check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726387/problem-running-a-monodevelop-app

Answer (score 1):

Somehow you have a version of the Mono for Android addin that doesn't match your MonoDevelop version. Try updating MD to 2.6 b2 and then update the addin through the addin manager.

Comment: I have MD 2.6 b3, is b2 still available?

Comment: b3 should be fine. What's the version of the addin shown in the addin manager?

Comment: the `mono for android` is version 2.6.4

Comment: Is there anything in ~/Library/Application Support/MonoDevelop-2.6/Addins?

Comment: Try removing them, they might be interfering with the ones included in MD.

Comment: all of them? how are those different from the ones included in MD?

Comment: What do you have in there? Those are addins you got from the addin server. Newer MD releases include bundled versions of some of them. It's possible there's a mismatch in the version of MD they're intended to target.

Comment: @mhutch have updated my question with a screenshot of what is there in my `addins` folder.

Comment: Oh, this is is windows? The path I gave was for Mac. In Windows 7 the user addins path is AppData\Local\MonoDevelop-2.6\Addins

Comment: Yes, it is Win7, should have mentioned it before, sorry about that, when I remove the `mono for Android` addIn from the specified folder, it is "going" from MD as well.

Comment: @mhutch updated my question further, could you set a bounty for this?

Comment: Might be a bug in the windows 2.6b3 package. The addin was supposed to be included in the MD installer since MD 2.6b2, so the one in the repo likely targeted 2.6b1.

Comment: Not sure, try MD 2.6 b1 or b2?

Comment: is it still available for download? any download links?

Comment: Just look at the 2.6 b3 download link and change the 3 to a 1 or a 2  :)